# Access to XMLHttpRequest CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, jhipster, tomcat9

I have front project using angular 7
and another backend project using jhipster spring boot

I use tomcat 9

I deploy the two project under tomcat 9

I can work with my application using @ip

I use this link **http://192.168.0.120/univesity**
and for backend api  : **http:192.168.0.120:8080/myapp**

now I have apache server which communicate with tomcat server .

so the application will be called like this :  **http://appuni.edu.com**  which will redirect to http://appuni.edu.com/univesity

I make this configuration in tomcat to redirect from **http://appuni.edu.com**  to **http://appuni.edu.com/univesity**

```
  <Context path="" docBase="univesity">
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>


</Context>
```

when I try to call my application using http://appuni.edu.com/univesity it display the login page

but I have this error when I try to login

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://http:192.168.0.120:8080/myapp/api/account' 
from origin 'http://appuni.edu.com' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I try with many solution without success

**in bakend project :**

I try to add in  **UserJWTController class**

```
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

also I try to add  in **configure(HttpSecurity http)  method**

```
antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
```

also I make  in **application.yml**

```
 cors:
         allowed-origins: "http://appuni.edu.com"
         allowed-methods: "*"
         allowed-headers: "*"
         exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count"
         allow-credentials: true
         max-age: 1800
```

**in front project :**

also I try to make in proxy.conf.json

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://appuni.edu.com",
        "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
       },
       "changeOrigin": true,
       "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

also I try to make  this code in auth-jwt.service.ts

```
 const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
  .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
  .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthServerProvider {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private $localStorage: LocalStorageService, private $sessionStorage: SessionStorageService) {}

    getToken() {
        return this.$localStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken') || this.$sessionStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken');
    }

    login(credentials): Observable<any> {
        const data = {
            username: credentials.username,
            password: credentials.password,
            rememberMe: credentials.rememberMe
        };
        return this.http.post(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/authenticate', data, {'observe': 'response',
        'headers':headers}).pipe(map(authenticateSuccess.bind(this)));

        function authenticateSuccess(resp) {
            const bearerToken = resp.headers.get('Authorization');
            console.log('bearerToken:' + bearerToken);

            if (bearerToken && bearerToken.slice(0, 7) === 'Bearer ') {
                const jwt = bearerToken.slice(7, bearerToken.length);
                this.storeAuthenticationToken(jwt, credentials.rememberMe);
                return jwt;
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know the problem is related to backend or to the front

using @Ip it works but using http://appuni.edu.com  it has problem

**Updated :**

I make this update :

```
 cors: 
         allowed-origins: "*"
         allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
         allowed-headers: "*"
         exposed-headers:
         allow-credentials: true
         max-age: 1800
```

and I add this line :

```
antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
```

but I have now this error :

**POST http:192.168.0.120:8080/myapp/api/authenticate 403**

this my configure method :

```
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf()
    .disable()
    .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
    .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
    .and()
    .headers()
    .frameOptions()
    .disable()
    .and()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll() 
    .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
    .and()
    .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());

  }
```

Comment: try on your front .append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")

Comment: thank you for response, using your solution I have same error

Comment: Did you notice double "http:" in the error `http://http:192.168.0.120:8080/myapp/api/account`?

Comment: sorry it's juse writing fault,  the error is  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http:192.168.0.120:8080/myapp/api/account'

Comment: I have updated my question :  now I have this error :  POST http:192.168.0.120:8080/myapp/api/authenticate 403